# Is there a way to add the results of a for loop to a dataframe when the result resets each iteration?

Tags: python, for-loop, google-analytics-api

I am querying the google analytics API and using a for loop for getting data from more than one view at a time. I then have a parser function that parses my JSON result into a pandas dataframe. If i print the function result it shows me every result in an individual data frame, for however many views i query. However i cant add the result to a new data frame or list each iteration.

i have tried using a while loop

```
df_new = []
view_id_list = ['##', '##', '##'] 
while len(df_new) < len(view_id_list)
    df2 = df_new.append(((prase_response_single(response_data)[0]))
```

this code is my sample request, that runs through my list of view_id's and brings me the data for each one individually

```py
for i in viewId_listUse:
    sample_request = {
        'viewId': i,
        'dateRanges': {
            'startDate': datetime.strftime(datetime.now() - timedelta(days=30), '%Y-%m-%d'),
            'endDate': datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), '%Y-%m-%d')
        },
        'dimensions': [{'name': 'ga:date'}],
        'metrics': [{'expression': 'ga:sessions'}]
    }
    response = api_client.reports().batchGet(
        body={
            'reportRequests': sample_request
        }).execute()

    response_data = response.get('reports', [])[0]
    print((prase_response_single(response_data)[0]))
```

this function parses the JSON data into a pandas data frame, but clears the resulting list each time it is called

```py
def prase_response_single(report):

    """Parses and prints the Analytics Reporting API V4 response"""
    result_list = []

    data_csv = []
    data_csv2 = []

    header_row = []

    columnHeader = report.get('columnHeader', {})
    metricHeaders = columnHeader.get('metricHeader', {}).get('metricHeaderEntries', [])
    dimensionHeaders = columnHeader.get('dimensions', [])

    for dheader in dimensionHeaders:
        header_row.append(dheader)
    for mheader in metricHeaders:
        header_row.append(mheader['name'])

    rows = report.get('data', {}).get('rows', [])
    for row in rows:
        row_temp = []
        dimensions = row.get('dimensions', [])
        metrics = row.get('metrics', [])
        for d in dimensions:
            row_temp.append(d)
        for m in metrics[0]['values']:
            row_temp.append(m)
            data_csv.append(row_temp)

        if len(metrics) == 2:
            row_temp2 = []
            for d in dimensions:
                row_temp2.append(d)
            for m in metrics[1]['values']:
                row_temp2.append(m)
            data_csv2.append(row_temp2)

    result_df = pandas.DataFrame(data_csv, columns=header_row)
    result_list.append(result_df)
    if data_csv2 != []:
        result_list.append(pandas.DataFrame(data_csv2, columns=header_row))

    return result_list
```

using the print function this is the kind of result i receive (with more rows but this is a format example)

```
 ga:date ga:sessions
0   20190522        1243
1   20190523        1167
2   20190524        1001
```

however i cant seem to append these individual data frames together, as the function resets its list every time it is called by the for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me like this is because you are overwriting the `result_list` variable each time you call the function.

```py
def prase_response_single(report):

    """Parses and prints the Analytics Reporting API V4 response"""
    # Each time the function is called, this is overwritten as an empty list
    result_list = [] 

    ...
```

However your first snippet seemed like it was collecting these smaller Dataframes all together into a list, so you have the complete list of Dataframes at the end. In that case you probably can just loop through that `df_new` variable and user [pandas.concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) to concatenate them together.

Also, it seems like you have an unnecessary assignment in that first snippet.

```
df_new = []
view_id_list = ['##', '##', '##'] 
while len(df_new) < len(view_id_list)
    # Don't need to re-assign the list, .append will mutate the existing list
    df_new.append(((prase_response_single(response_data)[0]))
```

Let me know if I was mistaken with what you were asking or if there's anything I can clarify.

Comment: thanks, you were right that using pd.concat worked, i ended up appending each data frame to a list and then running another for loop to pd.concat them all together one by one.